# Direct connection to some peer

Tags: peers, public-key, bootnodes

I have pub key of some peer (received it in block's header, it is need for some logic). 
I need make connection to it to send request.
If peers know each other it is not a problem. I catch it like this `peers.Peer(id)`, where `peers` is `*peerSet` and `id` - public key of peer.

But what I need to do, if this 2 peers not know each other. 
May I ask bootnode to send me a connection by public key?

Comment: I implemented request to bootnodes and can receive discover.Node. But I still can't add corresponding peer  to Downloader.peers list